# I am wondering if the SSD that I plan on buying will be compatible with my motherboard that I currently have

Tags: windows-10

My current motherboard is:A320 Micro-ATX Motherboard

The SSD I want:Samsung 860 EVO 500GB 2.5 Inch SATA III Internal SSD (MZ-76E500B/AM)

Are the two compatible with one another?

Comment: There's nothing really special about SSD's. Unless your motherboard is very old (+10 years) or otherwise does not have normal SATA connectors, it will work.

Comment: SSDs or HDDs aren't motherboard specific, but the interface type for drives are.  Normal interface types would be SATA (2.5"/3.5" drives), mSATA (51mm x 30mm), and M.2 (22mm x 30 - 110mm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough information in your question about which motherboard you have, but the A320 generation of motherboards are all modern and will have the necessary connections for a SATA hard drive. The Samsung EVO you have mentioned will have standard SATA connectors as well so there shouldn't be any issue with the 2 being compatible.